# Use two polarizing filter without liquid crystal between them to render static image

Tags: optics, polarization

I'm going to demonstrate the work of polarizing filter. I have a tablet for this purpose with disassembled LCD panel which is fine but it is bulky and overkill. Is there any other material that may act as liquid crystals. Something transparent for a naked eye but will shade the painted shape if placed between two filters?

Comment: What you want is a transmissive LCD display. You can get a cheap transparent digital clock for that demonstration: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41tl5nV1YAL._SY300_.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_rotation), many water solutions will rotate the plane of polarization. Probably the easiest to get is sucrose.

For your experiment to work  you will need to calibrate the concentration of the solution and the length of the path travelled by light. That is, it will not be enough to spray the filters with sugary water, you will need something like a fish tank full of sugar saturated water. Put a polarization filter at each end and done.

Comment: It's not quite as bad for e.g. D-Fructose, but why bother when we have liquid crystals and polarization foils that can do the same thing with a thin film?